# Possible significant error in proof of the spectral theorem, Brian C Hall, Quantum Theory for Mathematicians

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

Note/Edit: Read the below paragraphs for context. I think I found a counterexample, though I don't have the energy to work through it now. Suppose $\mathcal{H} = L^2([0,1],m) \oplus L^2([0,1],m)$ where $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure. Consider the "position" operator $X$ given by $Xf(x) = xf(x)$ and consider the operator $A$ given by $Af = 1_{[1/2,1]}f$, each operator is a bounded self-adjoint operator on $L^2([0,1],m)$. Then define the bounded self-adjoint operator $X \oplus A$ on $\mathcal{H}$ in the obvious way: $X \oplus A (f,g) = (Xf,Ag)$. You can look at Hall's construction of the $(W_j, \psi_j)$, but you can convince yourself that we could take $W_1 = L^2([0,1],m) \times \{0\}$ and have $\psi_1 = (1,0)$ (standard techniques using density of polynomials will then convince you that the closed span of the $(X \oplus A)^n \psi_1$ is $W_1$). Then note that $1 \in \sigma(X \oplus A|_{W_1})$, $1_{\{1\}}(X \oplus A) \neq 0$ (as $(0, 1_{[1/2,1]} g)$ is an eigenvector of $X \oplus A$ with eigenvalue $1$ for all $g \in L^2([1/2,1],m)$), hence $\mu(\{1\}) \neq 0$ but $\mu_{\psi_1}(\{1\}) = 0$, which contradicts surjectivity as I noted in the 3rd to last paragraph. Let me know if you think this works or doesn't. If if does then I guess there's a serious problem with the proof in the book.

So I am in the middle of reading through B.C. Hall's proof of the spectral theorem for bounded self-adjoint operators on separable Hilbert spaces, so this question is a little hard to state given the amount of context.

Let $A$ a self-adjoint bounded operator on a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Suppose $\{W_j, \psi_j\}$ is a (possibly finite) sequence of pairwise orthogonal subspaces of $\mathcal{H}$ s.t. they are invariant under $A$, for fixed $j$ the span of $A^n \psi_j$ is dense in $W_j$, and $\mathcal{H} = \bigoplus_j W_j$ (the orthogonal direct sum). Let $A_j = A|_{W_j}$. Let $\mu^A$, $\mu^{A_j}$ denote the projection valued measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\sigma(A), \sigma(A_j)$ resp. (where $\sigma(B)$ is the spectrum of $B$). Let $\mu_{\psi_j}$ be the positive measure given by $\mu_{\psi_j}(E) = (\psi_j, \mu^{A_j}(E) \psi_j)$. Let $\mu$ be a positive measure on $\mathcal{B}_{\sigma(A)}$ s.t. $\mu(E) =0 \iff \mu^A(E) = 0$. Then note that $\mu^{A_j}(E) = 1_E(A_j) = 1_E(A|_{W_j}) = 1_E(A)|_{W_j}$ (where we are referring to the functional calculus induced by the respective operators, and the last equality follows from a lemma). Thus $\mu(E) = 0$ implies $0=\mu^A(E)= 1_E(A)$, hence $\mu^{A_j}(E) = 1_E(A_j) = 1_E(A)|_{W_j} = 0$ which implies $\mu_{\psi_j}(E) = 0$. So $\mu_{\psi_j}$ is absolutely continuous w/r/t $\mu$ on $\mathcal{B}_{\sigma(A_j)}$. Let $\rho_j$ denote its Radon-Nikodym derivative.

Finally we get to the part I'm stuck at. The author now claims "one can easily see that" the map $f \mapsto \rho_j^{1/2}f$ is unitary from $L^2(\sigma(A_j), \mu_{\psi_j}) \to L^2(\sigma(A_j), \mu)$. It is easy to verify it is norm preserving but why is it surjective?

Note that we only showed that $\mu_{\psi_j}$ was absolutely continuous w/r/t $\mu$. I claim that we need the converse to hold. Suppose we had the converse. Then $\rho_j$ is a.e. (both $\mu$ and $\mu_{\psi_j}$ since these agree on null sets) to a function that is everywhere nonzero, so we can WLOG suppose that $\rho_j$ is everywhere nonzero. Then we note that $\int_{\sigma(A_j)} |f \rho_j^{-1/2}|^2 d\mu_{\psi_j} = \int_{\sigma(A_j)} |f|^2 \rho_j^{-1} \rho_j d\mu = \int_{\sigma(A_j)} |f|^2 d\mu$. So if $f \in L^2(\sigma(A_j), \mu)$, then $f\rho_j^{-1/2} \in L^2(\sigma(A_j), \mu_{\psi_j})$. So the map is onto. On the other hand if we have that the converse doesn't hold, by considering a set that is $\mu_{\psi_j}$ null but not $\mu$ null ($\mu$ can be taken to be a finite measure, we can WLOG suppose this set has finite measure), and considering the indicator function on this set, we can see that no function in $L^2(\sigma(A_j), \mu_{\psi_j})$ will map onto it.

So why does this converse hold (to me it doesn't seem like it actually does so it feels like there is a near fatal error in this proof)? I tried constructing examples, but they got confusing fast.

Sorry for the wall of text, the question is really deep into a long proof but I'm totally stuck and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any converse, if $\rho\ne0$ a.e. $\mu_\psi$. Let me drop the $j$ to type less. If $f\in L^2(\sigma(A),\mu)$, all you need for surjectivity is that $\rho^{-1/2}f\in L^2(\sigma(A),\mu_\psi)$. And that works: you have that, for any measurable nonnegative $g$, 
$$
\int_E g\,d\mu_\psi=\int_E g\,\rho\,d\mu. 
$$
Thus
$$
\int_{\sigma(A)}|\rho^{-1/2}\,f|^2\,d\mu_\psi=\int_{\sigma(A)}\rho^{-1}\,|f|^2\,\rho\,d\mu=\int_{\sigma(A)}|f|^2\,d\mu<\infty. 
$$
So $U$ is surjective: $f=U(\rho^{-1/2}f)$.

---

**More details about Hall's proof:** As written, the proof doesn't work. But it's more about the implementation than the idea. As written, the proof seems to work only when $H$ is separable, but that's an assumption over the whole book, so not an issue.

In Lemma 8.12, one should be more careful about the choice of $\mu$. Namely, instead of taking $\mu$ as described in its proof, one can take 
$$\tag1
\mu=\sum_k\tfrac1{k^2}\,\mu_{\psi_k}.
$$
Here, for the nontrivial part of the proof, if $\mu_{\psi_k}(E)=0$ fr all $k$, we have $\mu^A(E)\psi_k=0$, and then for any $f$ $$0=f\mu^A(E)\psi_k=\mu^A(E)\,f\psi_k.$$As $\psi_k$ is cyclic, we get that $\mu^A(E)=0$ each $W_k$, and so $\mu^A(E)=0$.

The other important observation is this: a point $\lambda\in \sigma(A)$ is an eigenvalue for $A$ if and only if $\mu(\{\lambda\})>0$. That is, the eigenvalues of $A$ are precisely the atoms of $\mu$. Indeed, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$, then there exists $j$ such that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $j$. As $A_j$ goes to the multiplication operator in $L^2(\sigma(A_j),\mu_{\psi_j})$, the eigenvalue equation says that there exists $g$ with  $\|g\|_2=1$
$$
tg(t)=\lambda g(t),\ \ \ \ t\in \sigma(A_j)\ \text{ a.e.}
$$
This forces $g(t)=0$ a.e. on $\sigma(A_j)\setminus\{\lambda\}$. Thus 
$$
1=\int_{\{\lambda\}} |g(t)|^2\,d\mu_{\psi_k}=|g(\lambda)|^2\,\mu_{\psi_k}(\{\lambda\})
$$
and so $\{\lambda\}$ is an atom for $\mu_{\psi_k}$.

Now, whenever there is an eigenvalue $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$, we can fix an orthonormal basis $\{\phi_r\}$ of eigevectors for it, and we can decompose the eigenspace as $\bigoplus_r \mathbb C\,\phi_r$, each invariant for $A$ with cyclic vector. What this means is that in the original decomposition in subspaces $W_j$ we may have all eigenvalues accounted for. In other words, each $\mu_{\psi_j}$ will be either a Dirac delta or a diffuse measure. So, after renaming and changing coefficients, we may write $(1)$ as 
$$\tag2
\mu=\sum_k\tfrac1{k^2}\delta_{\lambda_k} + \sum_k\tfrac1{k^2}\,\mu_{\psi_k},
$$
where each of the sums could be finite, and the $\mu_{\psi_k}$ are all diffuse.

Now suppose that $A_j=\{\lambda_k\}$. Then the Radon-Nikodym derivative is $c\,1_{\lambda_k}$ for an appropriate $c>0$. Indeed, 
$$
\int_{\sigma(A_j)}f\,1_{\lambda_k}\,d\mu=f(\lambda_k)\,\mu(\{\lambda_k\})=f(\lambda_k)\,\sum_{j:\ \lambda_j=\lambda_k}\mu_{\psi_j}(\{\lambda_k\})=f(\lambda_k)\,\sum_{j:\ \lambda_j=\lambda_k}\tfrac1{j^2}.
$$
In particular you get that $\mu_{\psi_k}$ and $\mu$ are mutually absolutely continuous on $A_j$.

When $A_j$ does not contain any eigenvalue, I know how to salvage the proof, but not with elementary arguments. I'll write them anyway. The result, stated in our context, is that if $\mu_{\psi_k}$ is diffuse, then $L^2(\sigma(A_j),\mu_{\psi_k})$ is isomorphic to $L^2([0,1],m)$ via a unitary that preserves the multiplication operator. Because both $\mu$ and $\mu_{\psi_k}$ are diffuse on $A_j$, we can map from one to the other via $L^2([0,1],m)$. The proof I know of this is about masas in von Neumann algebras. Namely, if $\mathcal A\subset B(H)$ is a diffuse masa, then there exists a unitary $U:H\to L^2[0,1]$ such that $U\mathcal A U^*=L^\infty[0,1]$ acting as multiplication operators (usually this result is quoted as "well-known" in von Neumann algebra literature, so written proofs do not abound; the one I know is [Lemma 2.3.6 in Sinclair-Smith's *Finite von Neumann Algebras and Masas*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=9mEodJdjhrMC&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=diffuse+masa+in+B(H)&source=bl&ots=k6CBvsHHG0&sig=ACfU3U1zbjFL14-uJ0Nn3yyyNb5rQrpR0g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi13pHqmu7oAhVBKH0KHRwuB-sQ6AEwAnoECAsQKw#v=onepage&q=diffuse%20masa%20in%20B(H)&f=false)). At this stage, I'm not sure if all the above can be done without the Spectral Theorem!

Comment: This argument certainly look like it works but the symbols only make sense if $\rho \neq 0$ $\mu_\psi$ a.e. Let me give an example of how it breaks down. Consider Lebesgue measure $m$ on $[0,1]$ and the 0 measure on $[0,1]$ call it $\nu$. Then the RN derivative gives $d\nu = 0 dm$. Thus ***the same argument*** gives a unitary map $L^2([0,1], \nu) \to L^2([0,1],m)$. But this clearly absurd, as the cardinality of $L^2([0,1],\nu)$ is 1. You are dividing $0/0$ on a non-trivial set in the above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the above unitary map works iff the underlying measures are equivalent: $\mu \ll \nu$ and $\nu \ll \mu$. Another way of seeing this is that the inverse of the unitary transform will also be given by a RN derivative, the existence of which depends on the equivalences of the measures

Comment: You are right. But Hall does claim that $\rho\ne0$ a.e.

Comment: Yeah, I guess he does, though basically that means that's the spot I should've flagged the proof as problematic. The claim that $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ exists and is nonzero $\nu$ a.e. is precisely the same as claiming $\nu$ and $\mu$ are equivalent (i.e. each is absolutely continuous w/r/t to the other). This is what I can't show/don't believe.

Comment: Doesn't my counter-example sketch work out? I think there is an issue.

Comment: I have no much time now, but I'll try to check the proof later.

Comment: But if you are choosing your measures, it is not clear to me that you can produce those measures withing Hall's proof (which I only saw superficially, so I cannot be sure).

Comment: Ok thanks! Let me know what you figure out. I basically have narrowed down my issue to proving the equivalence of the $\mu_{\psi_j}$ and $\mu$.

Comment: Ok, so I wrote some ideas. As stated in the book, and unless I'm missing something, I think the problem you found is essential.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the response. Basically the idea is if you choose your subspace decomposition more carefully, you can actually get that the measures are always equivalent (though not necessarily by very elementary arguments)? Final question: is the theorem given by Hall correct as stated?

Comment: Yes, and yes. $ $

Comment: Please be aware that I might be missing something, and there might be a more elementary way of checking that things do work. Some of us are really good at missing those things :D